# nginx/gunicorn connection hanging for 60 seconds

Tags: django, nginx, timeout, gunicorn

I'm doing a HTTP POST request against a nginx->gunicorn->Django app. Response body comes back quickly, but the request doesn't finish completely for about 60 more seconds.

By "finish completely" I mean that various clients I've tried (Chrome, wget, Android app I'm building) indicate that request is still in progress, as if waiting for more data. Listening in from Wireshark I see that all data arrives quickly, then after 60 seconds ACK FIN finally comes.

The same POST request on local development server (`./manage.py runserver`) executes quickly. Also, it executes quickly against gunicorn directly, bypassing nginx. Also works quickly in Apache/mod_wsgi setup.

GET requests have no issues. Even other POST requests are fine. One difference I'm aware of is that this specific request returns 201 not 200.

I figure it has someting to do with `Content-Length` headers, closed vs keepalive connections, but don't yet know how things are supposed to work correctly.

- Backend server (gunicorn) is currently closing connections, this makes sense.
- Should backend server include `Content-Length header`, or `Transfer-encoding: chunked`? Or should nginx be able to cope without these, and add them as needed?
- I assume connection keep-alive is good to have, and should not be disabled in nginx.

*Update:* Setting `keepalive_timeout` to 0 in `nginx.conf` fixes my problem. But, of course, keep-alive is gone. I'm still not sure what's the issue. Probably something in the stack (my Django app or gunicorn) doesn't implement chunked transfer correctly, and confuses clients.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your upstream server (gunicorn) is somehow holding the connection open on that specific api call - I don't know why (depends on your code, I think), but the default [`proxy_read_timeout`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_read_timeout) option in nginx is 60 seconds, so it sounds like this response isn't being received, for some reason.

I use a very similar setup and I don't notice any issues on POSTs generally, or any other requests.

Note that `return HttpResponse(status=201)` has caused me issues before - it seems Django prefers an explicitly empty body: `return HttpResponse("", status=201)` to work. I usually set *something* in the body where I'm expected to - this may be something to watch out for.